# Java Output Format With Indents As Code:

Tags: java, format

I generate .java files from a PrintWriter class. These generated files contain **many** nested for loops. To properly indent everything, I am currently using something like:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i + 2; j++)
{
    pw.print("    ");
}
pw.println("{");
```

Just to properly indent the single parentheses.

Obviously, I could just make a method to do this. I'm more wondering if there's a library that will handle indention and such of outputted code.

Comment: What language is your output?

Comment: @Mark Elliot he said Java: _I generate .java files from a PrintWriter class._

Comment: @Nivas: I guess my reading goggles (read: blinders) were on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be better off not doing that in your code ( I dont know of any library that formats PrintWriter.out statements ) and instead relying on some formatters after your Java program has completed generating your .java files.

Here's some formatters

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/beautifier.html

Jacobe -- is command-line driven and the personal edition is free.

Comment: This looks like a more perfect solution than that for which I asked; thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can either use javaparser to parse the output generated after parsing will be with standard indentation

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

With Javaparser printing a source code (with default pretty printer) is as simple as that.

```
CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse(<path to source file>);
System.ou.println(cu.toString());
```